# Creating m*n arrays from an array and a boolean "shared" array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The problem: I am trying to generate *m* vectors of *n* elements, based on a "packaged", or shorter, master vector, *V*, that is shorter than *m x n*, and a length *n* boolean vector that determines how elements are repeated. (Vectors explained more below). How the Master Vector is created, and the results used, are relevant only in that the format (Master and Boolean, resulting in *m x n*) must be respected.

For example, if Element 0 has a boolean of False, all *m* vectors will have the same value for Element 0, *V[0]*. If Element 1 has a boolean of True, then vector 0 will have Element 1 from *V[1]*, but vector 1 will have Element 1 from *V[6]*. A Master Vector, *V*, of;

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,10,30,40,60,100,300,400,600)
```

and a boolean vector of

```
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
```

should produce three resulting vectors;

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
[10.  2. 30. 40.  5. 60.]
[100.   2. 300. 400.   5. 600.]
```

Which share some elements, but not others. I have a methodology for this, but it relies on nested loops and if statements.
What I've tried: A working, but inefficient example with 3 resulting vectors of 6 elements:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6,10,30,40,60,100,300,400,600))
genome = np.array((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))

index = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    
    if i==0:
        pBase = p[0:genome.size]
        print(pBase)
    else:
        extra = np.zeros(genome.size)
        for j in range(0,genome.size):
            if genome[j]==True:
                extra[j] = p[genome.size+index]
                index += 1
        pSplit = np.where(genome==False, pBase, extra)
        print(pSplit)
```

returns (as expected):

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
[10.  2. 30. 40.  5. 60.]
[100.   2. 300. 400.   5. 600.]
```

taking 45.1 µs ± 2.4 µs per loop. This seems unnecessarily verbose and slow for what should hypothetically be an easy operation, but I don't know any alternative methods. Is there some combination of list comprehensions or alternative functions that can accomplish the same results in a faster and more pythonic fashion?

EDIT: The values of *V* will not always be as simple as *V*10^i, the given vector is just for a demonstration. The values could be considered arbitrary (Generated from another method, following no replicable pattern like 10^i).

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Where does `[6]` come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Am I understanding the following right: for the first vector, it takes the first `len(bolean vector)` elements. For the remaing vectors, if the value in the boolean vector is zero, it just takes the number on the same place in V as in the constructed vector. If it is 1 in the boolean vector, it takes the next yet unadded element from V.

Comment: Are you sure the input is correct? Aren't `50` and `500` missing?

Comment: Barmar: [6] is the first time a "new element" is needed. Since the original array is 6 elements, index 0:5, the first time a vector after the first one pulls a new element will be from position 6. The second time a new value is needed will come from position 7, and so on.

Spider has it correct.

Mozway: 50 and 500 are never needed since that element is "shared", or always the value of the first vector in that position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I the following performs the task in a cleaner manner, but you can let me know what you think.

```
def convert_vectors(master_vector, boolean_vector):
    """
    example:
    master_vector = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,30,40,60,100,300,400,600]
    boolean_vector = [1,0,1,1,0,1]
    result = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[10, 2, 30, 40, 5, 60],[100, 2, 300, 400, 5, 600]]
    """
    res = []  # result
    curIndexInMaster = 0  # index in master_vector
    while curIndexInMaster < len(master_vector):
        curArray = []  # current array
        for bool in boolean_vector:  # for each element in boolean_vector
            if bool:  # should get new element from master_vector
                curArray.append(master_vector[curIndexInMaster])
                curIndexInMaster += 1
            else:
                curArray.append(master_vector[len(curArray)])
                if curIndexInMaster < len(boolean_vector):  # only for first array
                    curIndexInMaster += 1
        res.append(curArray)
    return res


master_vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 30, 40, 60, 100, 300, 400, 600]
boolean_vector = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
print(convert_vectors(master_vector, boolean_vector))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [10, 2, 30, 40, 5, 60], [100, 2, 300, 400, 5, 600]]
```

Comment: 3.91 µs ± 405 ns per loop, an order of magnitude faster. Thank you, I think you've got the answer.

Comment: You should never use built in function or class names (like `bool`) as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

This program is working in another way, in order to also support vectors not having powers of 10. It first generates the base in vectors, and then adds as many vectors as needed. The vectors are generated in the following way: The program constructs vectors untill there are no mor elemnts in `remain`, which mains that the maximum contructable values is reached.
First, it copies `vector[0]`. Then, it iterates trough all elements of the genome vector. If the element is 1, it replaces the element in the new vector with the first value of `remain`, which contains all the yet unused values of `V`.

```py
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,30,40,60,100,300,400,600]
genome=[1,0,1,1,0,1]
vectors=[V[:len(genome)]]
remain=V[len(genome):]
genome_sum=sum(genome)
while len(remain)>=genome_sum:# no more vectors constructable
    newv=vectors[0].copy()
    for i,x in enumerate(genome):   
        if x==1:
            newv[i]=remain[0]
            del remain[0]
    
    vectors.append(newv)
```

Comment: I've updated the code, making it more efficient. I've also changed variable names, to make them more representive.

Comment: 13.8 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop, ~3x faster but not quite as fast as Plonetheus' answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that after some preparations (just 5 lines of code)
your task can be performed with a **single** instruction.

**Part 1**: Preparatory steps:

```
gs1 = genome.size             # Number of elements
gs2 = genome.sum()            # Number of "True" values
rowNo = (p.size - gs1) // gs2 # Number of rows to be filled "with spaces"
# Indices of "true" in "genome", repeated in as many rows as needed
idx_g = np.tile(np.where(genome)[0], rowNo).reshape(rowNo, -1)
res = np.tile(p[0:gs1], rowNo + 1).reshape(rowNo + 1, -1)   # The result (initial content)
```

**Part 2**: Actual computation:

```
np.put_along_axis(res[1:],    # Destination array
    idx_g,                    # Target indices in each row 
    p[gs1:].reshape(-1, gs2), # "Following" part of "p" cut into rows
    axis=1)                   # The axis to take 1D slices along
```

For detais see documentation of respective *Numpy* methods.

For your source data the result (*res* array) is:

```
[[  1   2   3   4   5   6]
 [ 10   2  30  40   5  60]
 [100   2 300 400   5 600]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - "res" from Part 1 seems to already have the correct answer (awesome!) but I get "none" as a return from Part 2.

Comment: *np.put_along_axis* does not return anything. In any doubts, check the documentation of this function. The result is in *res* array. Inspect what *res* contains after the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

V = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 30, 40, 60, 100, 300, 400, 600))
b = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]).astype(bool)

nc = len(b)
nr = (len(V) - len(b)) // b.sum() + 1
out = np.tile(V[:nc], reps=(nr, 1))
out[1:][np.tile(b, reps=(nr - 1, 1))] = V[nc:]
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[[  1   2   3   4   5   6]
 [ 10   2  30  40   5  60]
 [100   2 300 400   5 600]]
```

Comment: Very clean! I get 35.6 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop, a ~30% speed increase. Thank you!

Comment: @torridbeaver I was surprised that vectorized code would be outperformed by plain Python code, so I run some tests on my own. For small input arrays, I largely obtained the same timing results as you did. However, when the input arrays are larger (say, 100 elements in the boolean one, a few hundred in the other), vectorized code becomes several times faster than non-vectorized one.  So, for small arrays calls to numpy functions slow the code down, but for anything larger numpy is significantly more efficient, as one would expect.